# extracting theNamespace from the xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I am working on the XML files in C#.

I want to extact the name space and do some maniplations.

say my xml file looks like this.

```
        <Content xmlns="http://ABCD.com/sdltridion/schemas/XXXXX">
            <first>ABCD</first>
            <second>DCEF</second>
        </Content>
```

I want to extract Xml namespace from the root tag, ang get the value of XXXXX.

Output needed: XXXXX

Can any one help regarding this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace.NamespaceName;
var value = new Uri(ns).Segments.LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try XNamespace class

```
 XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://ABCD.com/sdltridion/schemas/XXXXX");
 var result = XElement.Load("URL").Descendants(ns + "NODENAME");
```

Thanks

Deepu